# Combine 2 excel sheets together through concatenate the individual data

Tags: excel, database, powerquery

i want to merge two excel sheet together through a reference key column. For the data, i will wish to concatenate them after the merge. So example:

Excel sheet 1

| Key Col | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | Value1 |  | Cell 1 |
| BBB | Value2 |  | Cell 2 |
| CCC | Value3 |  | Cell 3 |
| DDD | Value4 |  | Cell 4 |
| EEE | Value5 |  | Cell 5 |

Excel sheet 2

| Key Col | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA |  | Cell A |  |
| BBB |  | Cell B |  |
| CCC |  | Cell C |  |
| DDD |  | Cell D |  |
| EEE |  | Cell E |  |

Combined sheet

| Key Col | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | Value1 | Cell A | Cell 1 |
| BBB | Value2 | Cell B | Cell 2 |
| CCC | Value3 | Cell C | Cell 3 |
| DDD | Value4 | Cell D | Cell 4 |
| EEE | Value5 | Cell E | Cell 5 |

Both excel sheet data are from a SQL database and i hope to avoid using macros to achieve the final state if possible. The ideal scenario will be refresh the data to achieved the updated result. Is there any clean and streamline means to achieve this?

Comment: This question doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: It doesn't look like you actually researched this at all. [It is right in Microsoft's documentation.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/merge-queries-power-query-fd157620-5470-4c0f-b132-7ca2616d17f9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this tutorial [Merge Tables in Excel Using Power Query](https://trumpexcel.com/merge-tables/)

or

1. Import your data into PowerQuery using `Get data - from Table/Range`
2. Delete the empty columns
3. Merge the 2 tables:

[image]

4. Expand Table2

[image]

5. Load the result to a new sheet

[image]